# How to Show an element onclick onclick only if the user is logged in if not redirects to login using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I want to be able to show an element (phone number) which is initially hidden. I have a button called show phone which on click will display the element containing the phone number which was hidden. It is working quite alright but I want to add a new rule for it to show the phone number. I want it to show the phone number only if the user is logged in to his account if it will redirect to the login page with a flash message saying "In order to view this phone number you must be logged in". I tried to put an auth::check to the div and got stuck at this point.
Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve that using Laravel.

Here is my view

```
<span class="job-is ft"  id="more" onclick="$('.details').slideToggle(function(){$('#more').html($('.details').is(':visible')?'Hide Phone':'Show Phone');});">Voir le numero</span>
 @if (Auth::check()) 
<div class="extra-job-info details" style="display:none">
                                        <p style="text-align: center; padding: 10px; font-size: 45px;"><i class="la la-phone"></i> {{ $profiledetail->phone }}</p>
                                    </div>  
  @else 

  <p> In order to view this number you must login
 @endif
```

Do anyone know an easy way to achieve this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do not redirect the user; just add your check in the details box & tell the user if he wants to see the info he has to sign-in

Comment: Ok, I see. I edited my question. Can you check if it's what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
<span class="job-is ft"  id="more" onclick="$('.details').slideToggle(function(){$('#more').html($('.details').is(':visible')?'Hide Phone':'Show Phone');});">Voir le numero</span>

<div class="extra-job-info details" style="display:none">
    @if (Auth::check()) 
    <p style="text-align: center; padding: 10px; font-size: 45px;"><i class="la la-phone"></i> {{ $profiledetail->phone }}</p>
    @else
    <p>Please login to see details</p>
    @endif 
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, The answer is helpful and It's also another possibility. But please, I wish to know if there is a way to redirect the user  automatically when he clicks the show phone and he is not connected

Comment: Just add your if statement to the link itself or use a JavaScript code inside the else in my answer to redirect. In my opinion redirecting the user would be a bad user experience... just tell him he need to login & you can add a link to login page.